# Concurrent stack in C

Tags: c, multithreading, stack, pthreads, producer-consumer

(See also the [follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152969/concurrent-stack-in-c-follow-up).)

I was in the mood for `pthread.h` and decided to write a concurrent stack data structure. My requirements:

- the stack has maximum capacity,
- pushing an element,
- removing the top element without returning it,
- peeking the top element,
- client is blocked whenever popping from an empty stack,
- client is blocked whenever pushing to a full stack.

My codez looks like this:

**concurrent_stack.h**

```
#ifndef CONCURRENT_STACK_H
#define CONCURRENT_STACK_H

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct concurrent_stack
{

    /*******************************************
    The number of elements stored in this stack.
    *******************************************/
    size_t size;

    /**************************************************
    The maximum number of elements this stack can hold.
    **************************************************/
    size_t capacity;

    /**********************************************
    The actual array holding the data of the stack.
    **********************************************/
    void** storage;

    /************************************************
    The mutual exclusion lock for updating the stack.
    ************************************************/
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;

    /*****************************
    Guards against an empty stack.
    *****************************/
    pthread_cond_t  empty_condition_variable;

    /***************************
    Guards against a full stack.
    ***************************/
    pthread_cond_t  full_condition_variable;
}
concurrent_stack;

/*****************************************
Initializes a new, empty concurrent stack.
*****************************************/
void concurrent_stack_init(concurrent_stack* stack, size_t capacity);

/****************************************
Pushes a datum onto the top of the stack.
****************************************/
void concurrent_stack_push(concurrent_stack* stack, void* datum);

/******************************************
Returns, but does not remove the top datum.
******************************************/
void* concurrent_stack_top(concurrent_stack* stack);

/****************************************
Removes the topmost datum from the stack.
****************************************/
void concurrent_stack_pop(concurrent_stack* stack);

/*******************************************
Returns the number of elements in the stack.
*******************************************/
size_t concurrent_stack_size(concurrent_stack* stack);

/*********************************
Returns the capacity of the stack.
*********************************/
size_t concurrent_stack_capacity(concurrent_stack* stack);

/***********************************
Releases all resources of the stack.
***********************************/
void concurrent_stack_free(concurrent_stack* stack);

#endif /* CONCURRENT_STACK_H */
```

**concurrent_stack.c**

```
#include "concurrent_stack.h"
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX(A,B) (((A) > (B)) ? (A) : (B))

static const size_t MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 10;

void concurrent_stack_init(concurrent_stack* stack, size_t capacity)
{
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->capacity = MAX(capacity, MINIMUM_CAPACITY);
    stack->storage = malloc(sizeof(void*) * stack->capacity);
    pthread_mutex_init(&stack->mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&stack->empty_condition_variable, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&stack->full_condition_variable, NULL);
}

void concurrent_stack_push(concurrent_stack* stack, void* datum)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);

    while (stack->size == stack->capacity)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&stack->full_condition_variable, &stack->mutex);
    }

    stack->storage[stack->size++] = datum;

    pthread_cond_signal(&stack->empty_condition_variable);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);
}

void concurrent_stack_pop(concurrent_stack* stack)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);

    while (stack->size == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&stack->empty_condition_variable, &stack->mutex);
    }

    stack->size--;

    pthread_cond_signal(&stack->full_condition_variable);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);
}

void* concurrent_stack_top(concurrent_stack* stack)
{
    void* ret;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);

    while (stack->size == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&stack->empty_condition_variable, &stack->mutex);
    }

    ret = stack->storage[stack->size - 1];

    pthread_cond_signal(&stack->full_condition_variable);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);

    return ret;
}

size_t concurrent_stack_size(concurrent_stack* stack)
{
    size_t size;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);
    size = stack->size;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);

    return size;
}

size_t concurrent_stack_capacity(concurrent_stack* stack)
{
    return stack->capacity;
}

void concurrent_stack_free(concurrent_stack* stack)
{
    free(stack->storage);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&stack->mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&stack->empty_condition_variable);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&stack->full_condition_variable);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "concurrent_stack.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct thread_config
{
    size_t element_count;
    concurrent_stack* stack;
}
thread_config;

void* producer_code(void* data)
{
    thread_config* cfg = (thread_config*) data;
    size_t limit = cfg->element_count;
    concurrent_stack* stack = cfg->stack;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != limit; ++i)
    {
        concurrent_stack_push(stack, (void*) i);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void* inspector_code(void* data)
{
    thread_config* cfg = (thread_config*) data;
    size_t limit = cfg->element_count;
    concurrent_stack* stack = cfg->stack;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != limit; ++i)
    {
        concurrent_stack_top(stack);
        concurrent_stack_size(stack);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void* consumer_code(void* data)
{
    thread_config* cfg = (thread_config*) data;
    size_t limit = cfg->element_count;
    concurrent_stack* stack = cfg->stack;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != limit; ++i)
    {
        concurrent_stack_pop(stack);
    }

    return NULL;
}

static const size_t PRODUCERS = 3;
static const size_t CONSUMERS = 3;
static const size_t INSPECTORS = 1;

static const size_t PRODUCER_ELEMENTS = 91 * 1000;
static const size_t CONSUMER_ELEMENTS = 90 * 1000;
static const size_t INSPECTOR_ELEMENTS = 50 * 1000;

/**
In order to make sure that the program exits, you must guarantee that:

PRODUCER_ELEMENTS * PRODUCERS - CONSUMER_ELEMENTS * CONSUMERS <= STACK_CAPACITY.

Otherwise, after all consumers have done their job, the producers will fill 
it again and finally block on it.
*/
static const size_t STACK_CAPACITY = 5000;

int main()
{
    concurrent_stack st;
    concurrent_stack_init(&st, STACK_CAPACITY);

    pthread_t threads[PRODUCERS + CONSUMERS + INSPECTORS];
    size_t next_thread_slot = 0;

    thread_config producer_thread_config = { PRODUCER_ELEMENTS, &st };
    thread_config consumer_thread_config = { CONSUMER_ELEMENTS, &st };
    thread_config inspector_thread_config = { INSPECTOR_ELEMENTS, &st };

    for (size_t i = 0; i != CONSUMERS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[next_thread_slot++],
                       NULL,
                       consumer_code,
                       (void*) &consumer_thread_config);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i != INSPECTORS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[next_thread_slot++],
                       NULL,
                       inspector_code,
                       (void*) &inspector_thread_config);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i != PRODUCERS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[next_thread_slot++],
                       NULL,
                       producer_code,
                       (void*) &producer_thread_config);
    }

    /* All threads created. Now join them. */

    for (size_t i = 0; i != INSPECTORS + CONSUMERS + PRODUCERS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    size_t expected_stack_size =
        PRODUCERS * PRODUCER_ELEMENTS - CONSUMERS * CONSUMER_ELEMENTS;

    printf("Expected final stack size: %zu\n", expected_stack_size);
    printf("Actual final stack size:   %zu\n", concurrent_stack_size(&st));
    concurrent_stack_free(&st);
}
```

**Critique request**

Please tell me anything that comes to mind, yet especially I am interested in comments relating to:

- code layout,
- correctness of synchronization.

Comment: I'd suggest you remove that part of your requests regarding  _coding conventions_. I't makes your question overly broad and opinion based, since there aren't any general coding conventions for c.

Comment: That's absolutely false @πάντα ῥεῖ, OP can specify where exactly he is looking for improvements and what type of improvements he is more interested in. Any specific request are on-topic as well. This makes it easier for reviewers to focus on specific parts of the code instead of pointing out all of the code-style, naming, etc. errors, which doesn't really concern OP all that much.

Comment: @denis No, that's not _false_. Coding conventions vary on many points of view, and are contradictorily if you don't follow the whole set of them. I think the OP's edit improved the question a lot! I'll keep to flag/VTC any question about _better coding conventions_ in future.

Comment: I see, you were talking specifically about the coding conventions part, I do agree on that one, my bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Extraneous line

I quickly scanned your stack code and it looked correct to me.  However, I did spot an extraneous line in `concurrent_stack_top()`.  You have this line that was probably copied from `concurrent_stack_pop()`:

```
    pthread_cond_signal(&stack->full_condition_variable);
```

Since `concurrent_stack_top()` doesn't remove anything from the stack, you shouldn't need to signal anything to the producers.

#### Pop should return top also

I think that `pop()` should return the top element, so that the operation is atomic.   Otherwise, if you do `top()` followed by `pop()`, you might get some element from `top()` but then pop a different element.

Answer (score 7):

### Issues:

Failed to check the return value of all these system calls:

```
stack->storage = malloc(sizeof(void*) * stack->capacity);
pthread_mutex_init(&stack->mutex, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&stack->empty_condition_variable, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&stack->full_condition_variable, NULL);
pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&stack->full_condition_variable, &stack->mutex);
pthread_cond_signal(&stack->empty_condition_variable);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&stack->empty_condition_variable, &stack->mutex);
pthread_cond_signal(&stack->full_condition_variable);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&stack->empty_condition_variable, &stack->mutex);
pthread_cond_signal(&stack->full_condition_variable);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_mutex_lock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&stack->mutex);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&stack->mutex);
pthread_cond_destroy(&stack->empty_condition_variable);
pthread_cond_destroy(&stack->full_condition_variable);
```

You **may** be destroying objects that are currently in use in another thread.

```
void concurrent_stack_free(concurrent_stack* stack)
{
    free(stack->storage);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&stack->mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&stack->empty_condition_variable);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&stack->full_condition_variable);
}
```

Before you can start freeing the resources you have to make sure that no other thread is using these resources. This means you have to force a flush and make sure there are no threads in your object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A couple of questions though: (1) What should I do, if a pthread call fails? (2) How to make sure that `concurrent_stack_free` does the job such that no other threads are using the stack?

Comment: What should you do? What can you do? Can your code continue if the pthread call fails? If it can't then an error message and a call to `exit()` seem appropriate. Continuing without doing anything should never be an option.